# How to know "From which website user came to Google Play?"

Tags: android, google-play

Is there a way to know where from user came to Google Play before installing our app?

Like, user may click on some ad and navigate to Google Play.

Does Google Play have any such API. I don't think it's possible to know that. But, is there an alternative approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do it for your own app, I think you are looking for *Campaign tracking - via Analytics*.

> For example, you could use Custom Campaigns to find out if more users
>   arrive at your download page in an app marketplace from an in-app ad
>   or a search ad. You could also use Custom Campaigns to find out how
>   many users come to your web site from a link that was included in a
>   monthly email newsletter.

Refer [Custom Campaigns](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033863?hl=en).

> Use the Google Play URL builder tool to help define and append URL
>   parameters. You must also have [Google Play Campaign Attribution](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/campaigns#google-play-implement) set up
>   in your SDK. If you didn’t complete this during your initial set up,
>   use our Developer Guide to learn how to implement Google Play
>   Attribution in your Android SDK.

With analytics in your app, you can get reports for - *from where was your app downloaded*.

The **[Google Play URL builder tool](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en&ref_topic=1032998)** explains what you need to specify:
**Campaign's  source, medium, term, content and name.**

With the Analytics code in your app, after a user installs the app, the relevant info will be relayed to your app's analytics page.

**For eg.** If you have an html page, which contains the add to your app, specify the campaign terms- source, medium etc in its url and when the user clicks on it, he/she is redirected to the Play Store. If your app is installed like that.. the corresponding campaign source, medium and details will be registered.

Read more: [Best Practices for creating Custom Campaigns](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1037445?hl=en&ref_topic=1032998)